# Make an index loop through an array and print elements out?

Tags: java, arrays

The code bellow should be printing out the elements of my array, instead, it prints out the first element again and again without ever ending. I don't know if it's a simple thing but I could not manage to find my mistake. Help would be appreciated even though this question might be easy for most of you.

```
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        int[] myintarray = {12,32,34};
        int index= 0;
        while(index < 3)
        System.out.println(myintarray[index]);
        index++;
    }
}
```

Actual result: 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 ... 12
Expected result: 12 32 34

Best regards,

Comment: Put braces around your loop block, otherwise `index++` is unreachable. (or, better yet, try a `for` loop!).

Comment: Always. Always. ALWAYS use braces around the body of your loops (even if the body is just a single statement) and you'll never have this problem again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `index` is not updated inside your loop: it stays at it's initial value (`index = 0`) which is why it always prints the first value in your array. Also, since `index` is never updated, the condition `index < 3` is always `true` which is why your loop never ends.

Adding braces around the body of your while loop solves your problem:

```java
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] myIntArray = {12, 32, 34};
    int index = 0;
    while (index < 3) {
      System.out.println(myIntArray[index]);
      index++;
    }
  }
```

Output:

```
12
32
34
```

In your version, the body of the while loop is the single line: `System.out.println(myintarray[index]);`

Answer (score 1):

In a while without braces, only the statement that comes right after your whilte will be executed.

In your case, this means that only the first statement after the while will be looped through, which would be "System.out.println(myintarray[index]);".

Since the "index++;" is not reached, your index will have the same value, 0, therefore your program will always print the first element of your array. Your code scope, as it is, would be translated in braces to:

```
while(index < 3) {
    System.out.println(myintarray[index]);
}
index++;
```

To execute more than one statement, wrap it all around braces.

```
while(index < 3) {
    System.out.println(myintarray[index]);
    index++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are not putting braces around the code intended to go inside the while loop. You see, when a while loop or a for loop has no braces attached to it, in most languages, the loop will only consider the next command to be inside of it, which will then be the only command that will be run by the loop.

So, when running your program, the program only repeats "System.out.println(myintarray[index])", and never increases index, so the value of "myintarray[index]" is stuck at 12 forever.

So, we can solve this two ways:

```
int index = 0;
while(index < 3)
{
    System.out.println(myintarray[index]);
    index++;
}
```

or, if we wanted to use for loops,

```
for(int index = 0; index < 3, index++)
{
    System.out.println(myintarray[index]);
}
```